# Going to Tunisia as an EU citizen: is a hotel booking required?

Tags: bookings, eu-citizens, proof-of-accommodation, lithuanian-citizens, tunisia

I want to fly to Tunisia to visit a friend this January. I am an EU citizen, so I don't need to get visa in advance, but do I need proof of a booked hotel? Can I stay with my friend at their home? Or can I rent a flat from someone?

Comment: A letter of invitation from the friend might be useful. However, bear in mind that it is illegal to live or stay as an unmarried couple https://www.worldnomads.com/explore/north-africa/tunisia/local-laws-and-customs-tunisia

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't need Hotel booking or any proof. Nor there will be any question on this.

I am living here for 10 years and have many EU friends.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely what user22132 has said, when I visited Tunisia as a EU citizen I was asked to show them my hotel reservation and they insisted to see the proof of the payment too. I visited during summer 2022 if it helps.

Comment: Did you enter with a Passport or ID? The German Travel advice states that when entering with an ID an Hotelbooking is required [Tunesien: Reise- und Sicherheitshinweise - Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/tunesiensicherheit/219024?openAccordionId=item-301216-1-panel)

Comment: I entered with passport.